# Meaning and difference between ACP and MACP

Tags: india, employment, pensions

Can anyone please explain the meaning of assured career progression (ACP) and modified assured career progression (MACP) and the difference between the two?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7th_Central_Pay_Commission_(CPC)_and_Defence_Forces), these are related to *the principles and structure of emoluments of all central government civilian employees including defence forces in India*, however, it's not clear what these policies are specifically and how the two differ.

Comment: We need some more specifics. These look like terms people could Google, but what country are you talking about?

Comment: It is related to government employment and increment in employees' grade pay. I am talking about India.

Comment: People might look them up, but by defining precisely what you are looking for, you might get more/better answers. And it would be more useful for future visitors of the site.

Comment: Out of interests, this link: https://90paisa.blogspot.de/2009/06/acp-vs-macp.html discusses the difference between the two in India.

Comment: Seeing that this is a well-trafficked question related to the pay and structure of the Indian Government, I decided to add a little bit of research so it might be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

ACP is Assured Career Progression and MACP is Modified Assured Career Progression.

ACP gives you two financial hikes in salary after completion of 12 & 24 years of service without promotion, in Promotional Hierarchy while

MACP gives three financial hikes in salary after completion of 10, 20 & 30 years service without promotion in the next available pay scale/grade pay in your orginisation/PSU/Central Govt.

In ACP if one gets normal promotion after completion of say six years service then he has to wait till completion of total 24 years of service for becoming eligible for second ACP.

In MACP if one gets normal promotion after completion of say six years service then he becomes eligible for 2nd MACP after completion of 10 years from first promotion i.e. after 6 + 10 = 16 years.